# I am trying to bind a fragment to another using view binding

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, binding

I am trying to use the binding method in android studio to connect two fragments using onCreate and onViewCreated methods. so far i am getting id not resolved error. I have already connected the fragments on the xml graph. Bellow is the code of the settings java file.
I am new to android development pls help

error says
**Cannot resolve symbol 'R'**

**Cannot resolve symbol 'navController'**

*settingsFragment*

```java
package com.mqtt.workactiv.ui.settings;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.mqtt.workactiv.databinding.FragmentSettingsBinding;

public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentSettingsBinding binding;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SettingsViewModel settingsViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SettingsViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        binding.gatewayConnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_navigation_setting_to_accountFragment);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

*navgraph.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_setting">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.mqtt.workactiv.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_control"
        android:name="com.mqtt.workactiv.ui.control.ControlFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_control"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_control" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_setting"
        android:name="com.mqtt.workactiv.ui.settings.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_setting_to_accountFragment"
            app:destination="@id/accountFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/accountFragment"
        android:name="com.mqtt.workactiv.ui.AccountFragment"
        android:label="fragment_account"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account" />
</navigation>
```

*mainActivity.java

```java
package com.mqtt.workactiv;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.mqtt.workactiv.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);

        this.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getColor(R.color.gray_background));
        this.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getColor(R.color.white));
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by add adding my project package.R.id

**example**

*com.project.package.R.id*

```
com.mqtt.workactiv.R.id.action_navigation_setting_to_gatewayFragment
```

reference for other methods of solving the issue [solutions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-fix-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio/)